# Sample java spark program to read and load json file as a RDD

Tags: json, apache-spark

I am looking for a sample java program that can read a local json file in spark.

Comment: Best way to find basic information is to read technology documents

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

The example is part of the documentation at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets:

```
// sc is an existing JavaSparkContext.
SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

// A JSON dataset is pointed to by path.
// The path can be either a single text file or a directory storing text files.
DataFrame people = sqlContext.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to create your own class of that specific jsonFormat and in spark sc.textFile you have to create objects of that class and return rdd of those objects otherwise you will need to implement json record reader which will implement this interface RecordReader[Key, Value].